# APC was installed but doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, apc

I have this with php -i | grep apc :

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini, 
apc
apc.cache_by_default => On => On
apc.canonicalize => On => On
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => On => On
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.file_md5 => Off => Off
apc.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
apc.filters => no value => no value
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.include_once_override => Off => Off
apc.lazy_classes => Off => Off
apc.lazy_functions => Off => Off
apc.max_file_size => 1M => 1M
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.num_files_hint => 1000 => 1000
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.report_autofilter => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867 => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867_freq => 0 => 0
apc.rfc1867_name => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix => upload_ => upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.serializer => default => default
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.stat => On => On
apc.stat_ctime => Off => Off
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.user_entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.user_ttl => 0 => 0
apc.write_lock => On => On
```

And in php.ini :

```
[APC]
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=128M
apc.stat=1
```

But the generated time is high with Symfony2 (800ms instead of 80ms before formating), and if we look the result of grep, we can see apc.shm_size = 32M instand of 128.

And this is phpinfo() : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/36/1378406375-capture-du-2013-09-05-20-38-29.png

Any idea please? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered that PHP on the command line is a completely different PHP, also in regards to configuration, than the PHP working in the webserver? You cannot detect the configuration of the other PHP with a call to any one PHP. Use `phpinfo()` in a web page if you want to know how the PHP in the web server is configured.

Comment: Yes PHP works, I've this : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/36/1378406375-capture-du-2013-09-05-20-38-29.png with phpinfo()

Comment: Now the bad thing is: The setting you are complaining about is missing in your screenshot. Can you verify that APC is actually set to `apc.shm_size=128`? And then we need to think about the usefulness of 128 Bytes of APC cache memory, when the default is 32 MEGA bytes.

Comment: That the following configuration: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/36/1378408429-capture-du-2013-09-05-21-13-35.png we can see the shm_size is 128 Mega. That's right, at the beginning i've forgot the "M". Sorry.

Comment: Ok, having only 128 bytes of cache would have explained it a bit. Did you fetch the APC cache info? `var_dump(apc_cache_info());`, http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cache-info.php

Comment: I have a lot of thing : http://pastebin.com/9jvZ77T7

Comment: That looks like it's working to me.

Comment: That's strange, before my formating i have 70ms/page and now 700-900ms/page... I don't understand, i don't have modified my files.

Comment: What kind of formatting?

Comment: Before I had Ubuntu 12.04 and now elementaryOS based on ubuntu 12.10. The problem come form my configuration, I don't see others causes...

Comment: So your real story is: You installed a new system, and now your web application is running very slowly. You prematurely assumed that APC is to blame, but it is not.

Comment: You think is the new system? There is nothing to do?

Comment: I don't know your system or how to detect what the problem is. I wanted to highlight that you asked the wrong question. You should probably try it again.

Comment: Ok I'll search, thanks :)